# MongoServer.GetDatabase does not return the same instance

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

According to the code documentation `MongoServer.GetDatabase`:

> Gets a MongoDatabase instance representing a database on this server.
>   Only one instance is created for each combination of database
>   settings.

However, the following test fails (I get a different instance back despite the database name being the same):

```
void describe_get_database()
{
    MongoServer server = null;
    MongoDatabase db = null;
    MongoDatabase db2 = null;
    string dbName = null;

    before = () =>
    {
        var client = new MongoClient("mongodb://localhost");
        server = client.GetServer();

        dbName = "test";
        db = server.GetDatabase(dbName);
    };

    act = () => db2 = server.GetDatabase(dbName);

    context["when the database name is the same"] = () =>
    {
        it["should return the same database instance"] =
            () => db2.should_be_same(db);
    };
}
```

Have I misunderstood the documentation?

Answer (score 0):

I do agree with  Ben's observation and question on this issue.

I even digged into the Mongo c# driver source code at [https://searchcode.com/codesearch/view/26539464/], and it shows no clue that only one instance is created.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets a MongoDatabase instance representing a database on this server. Only one instance
    /// is created for each combination of database settings.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="databaseName">The name of the database.</param>
    /// <param name="databaseSettings">The settings to use with this database.</param>
    /// <returns>A new or existing instance of MongoDatabase.</returns>
    public virtual MongoDatabase GetDatabase(string databaseName, MongoDatabaseSettings databaseSettings)
    {
        if (databaseName == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("databaseName");
        }
        if (databaseSettings == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("databaseSettings");
        }
        return new MongoDatabase(this, databaseName, databaseSettings);
    }
```